# Auto scrolling (snapping) text with CSS only?

Tags: css

At the moment I have a CSS autoscrolling text that looks like this:

```
.vscroll {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
  transform:translateY(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
 }
 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 }
 @keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   {
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

This works, but it does look a bit choppy on some devices. So I am hoping it is possible to do something like this but with only CSS instead of jQuery: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Vertical-Text-Scrolling-Plugin-With-jQuery-scrollText-js/

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help (Sample).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>

<!-- Styles --> 
<style>
.example1 {
 height: 50px; 
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.example1 h3 {
 font-size: 3em;
 color: limegreen;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); 
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */ 
 -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes example1 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);   
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
</style>

<!-- HTML --> 
<div class="example1">
<h3>Scrolling text... </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly that is a normal scrolling text like I have working. What I am looking for is this but in pure CSS: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Vertical-Text-Scrolling-Plugin-With-jQuery-scrollText-js/